# How to retrieve a different attribute from a duplicate row into a new column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
att1 att2
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 2 |
| b | 3 |
```

And I need the different record of att2 for the duplicate value on att1 to be grouped into a new column like this

```
att1 att2 att3
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 3 |
```

I tried to pivot, I tried to self join, but I can't seem to find the query to separate the values like this. Can someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Could there be more than one duplicate?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes there are three rows with the same value on att1! Thanks for replying :)

Comment: You're going to need dynamic SQL for this.  Why do you want such a format?

Comment: I need it to report the values to several entities, being att1 one entity and att2 another. And it's quite easier to pivot the table when it is in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Use method of `Stuff` with `XML` to achieve the above result would be simple.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       AA.att1,
       split.a.value('/X[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [att2],
       split.a.value('/X[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [att3]
FROM
(
    SELECT A.att1,
           CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(A.att2, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               T.att1,
               att2 = STUFF(
                           (
                               SELECT DISTINCT
                                      ','+att2
                               FROM <table_name>
                               WHERE att1 = T.att1 FOR XML PATH('')
                           ), 1, 1, '')
        FROM <table_name> T
    ) A
) AA
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS split(a);
```

**Final Result :**

```
att1 att2 att3
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a known or maximum number of columns and you don't want to go dynamic

**Example**

```
Select att1
      ,att2 = max(case when RN=2 then att2 end)
      ,att3 = max(case when RN=3 then att2 end)
 From ( 
        Select *
              ,RN = 1+Row_Number() over (Partition By att1 order by att2)
         From  YourTable
       ) A
 Group By att1
```

**Returns**

```
att1    att2    att3
a       1       2
b       2       3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a query with the combination of XML Path and built-in STUFF function. that way you can achieve the result you want with dynamic column count.

see this page for an example:

https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/

and a sample query from the page above, which accomplishes what you need:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF(
                 (
                     SELECT DISTINCT
                            ','+QUOTENAME(c.[DocName])
                     FROM [dbo].[InsuranceClaims] c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
SET @query = 'SELECT [PolNumber], '+@cols+'from (SELECT [PolNumber],
           [PolType],
           [submitted] AS [amount],
           [DocName] AS [category]
    FROM [dbo].[InsuranceClaims]
    )x pivot (max(amount) for category in ('+@cols+')) p';
EXECUTE (@query);
```

Comment: you are welcome, please accept as answer if this is the answer you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t

CREATE TABLE #t(att1 VARCHAR(10) ,att2 INT)
INSERT INTO #t(att1,att2)

SELECT  'a' AS att1, 1 AS att2 UNION ALL
SELECT  'a' , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT  'b' , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT  'b' , 3 

SELECT * FROM #t
```

using lag and cte we could get the result

```
 ;With cte
AS
(
SELECT        
         Att1, 
         Att2, 
         CASE 
           WHEN Att1 = Att3 THEN MAX(Att2)OVER(Partition by Att1 order by Att1) 
         END att3 
         FROM   (

         SELECT Att1, 
                        Lag(Att1, 1) 
                          OVER ( 
                            ORDER BY Att1)AS att3, 
                        Att2 
                 FROM   #t
                 )dt
    ),
    CTe2
    AS
    (

    SELECT *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER( 
                    PARTITION BY Att1
                    ORDER BY Att1) AS RNk 
         FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Att1, 
                                 Att2, 
                                 Max(Att3) 
                                   OVER( 
                                    Partition by Att1 ORDER BY Att1) AS att3 
                 FROM   cte)dt
                 )

  SELECT att1,Att2,att3 FROM CTe2 WHERE RNk=1
```

Result

```
Att1    Att2    Att3
---------------------
a       1       2
b       2       3
```